SocketIO adapter stopped working after scaling (reboot) of the server
I am currently using Redis to cache calls and as state manager for SocketIO. My server is hosted on AWS and I had redis on micro instance and both NodeJS app and Socket server adapter connected successfully. I scaled Redis to xlarge instance and since then server is connecting fine, but Socket is reporting error: Connection timeout Error: Connection timeout. If I remove adapter, Socket works fine, but without state management.
Any ideas what could be the issue?
This is how I connect to my Socket with adapter.
        const pubClient = createClient({
            url: process.env.REDIS_URL,
            password: process.env.REDIS_PWD
        });
        const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

        await Promise.all([
            pubClient.connect(),
            subClient.connect()
        ]);
          
        const io = new Server(server, {
            adapter: createAdapter(pubClient, subClient),
            path: "/socket/socket.io",
            allowEIO3: true,
            cors: {
                origin: process.env.SOCKET_WHITELIST_DOMAIN.split(' '),
                credentials: true
            }
        });

